# Best Way to Grab Referring URL on .apk android app install

Tags: android, url, apk

I have an APK that is installed via a website. I have some url parameters/variables that are part of the download url that I want to use in the app for tracking purposes. My issue is how to get the Url and parameters via the app.

I did a fair amount of research but from what I can determine Android sandboxes its cookies so that path would not work. Any other ways to grab this info, I only need it for when the APK is downloaded from Phones web browser.

Comment: You may have better luck providing trivially different versions

Comment: if it was a few changes in the url variables but one of the variables is unique to each download and therefore I would have to create a version for each APK, which is too much

Comment: An apk is just a zipfile, on-the-fly generation is not necessarily unreasonable (some webservers will negotiate with the client to see if they might on-the-fly compress pages anyway).  Hopefully you can figure out how to change something that doesn't require re-signing, so that you can avoid having the server need to know the key.

Comment: That could work, but it is not the route I wish to take, I just want to know how to get the information without creating new APK's eachtime